# iOS universal link is not working in Nginx/Wordpress?

Tags: ios, nginx, webserver, apple-app-site-associate

I setup a wordpress site in my Nginx server and setup iOS universal link on it, but still it's not working and I'm struggling since a week :(

Here are the configurations I did :

nginx.conf file :

```
 location /apple-app-site-association {

        default_type application/application/json;

    }
```

apple-app-site-association file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "S23DDHF.com.abcd.app",
        "paths": [ "*", "/"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I try curl the url : https://abcd.app/apple-app-site-association I get the following output.

[image]

Anything I've missed ? can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The type is `application/json` , not `application/application/json`